# Make a before day folders using Dataflow(Datetime Function)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to create a folder with the previous day's date in its name.
Now, using this function

```
concat('src_planopos/delta/store_daily/year=',toString(currentDate('UTC'),'yyyy'),'/month=',toString(currentDate('UTC'),'MM'),'/day=',toString(currentDate('UTC'),'dd'))
```

year=2022/month=08/day=30
folder structure.
However, if we were to change this to
year=2022/month=08/day=29
We need to rewrite the function so that it becomes
Do I use "addDays"?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below expression in the dynamic content for the required result in ADF.
As you said, you can use `addDays()` for this.

```
Folder/year=@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-1),'yyyy')}/month=@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-1),'MM')}/day=@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-1),'dd')}/mycsv.csv
```

Please follow the below demonstration:

I have created a dataset parameter and given in the dataset.

[image]

Give the above expression in the dynamic content. Here I have used a variable and given in the copy activity sink.

[image]

**Sink:**

[image]

**Result in blob:**

[image]

**Update:** in Dataflows

In Dataflows we cannot give the values for the dataset path. we have to pass the folder path from ADF dynamic content only.

[image]

The path we have to give either in the dataset or in the pipeline. But both can only be a dynamic content.
After giving the above dataset in the sink of the dataset, when you see the pipeline of the dataflow it will ask you to give the value for the path variable.

Now pass the same variable or give same dynamic content expression.

[image]

This will give you the same result as above.

Comment: Sorry, my question was wrong.
Could you please tell me in the Dataflow function, not in ADF?

Comment: @CuteeeeRabbit, I have updated my answer above. please check that.